# Why drop down list value is not passed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am filling DDL dynamically :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" Style="width: auto" runat="server" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

With this function :

```
private void initTimeZone()
{
    var timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZone in timeZones)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem()
        {
            Text = timeZone.DisplayName,
            Value = timeZone.Id
        };
        ddlTimeZone.Items.Add(item);
    }        
}
```

Everything works fine but when I try to get the selected value I get an empty string

```
string item = ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue; -> empty string..
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you call `initTimeZone` method? Is it in `Page_Load`?

Comment: have you put that inside an `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}`?

Comment: in page_load function
 if (!IsPostBack){ initTimeZone();    }

Comment: Where is this code located: `string item = ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue;` ?

Comment: in the cs file attached to my aspx page.

Comment: @user2560521 no I mean in which method? Maybe you should add the code of the method that contains `string item = ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue;`

Comment: if your initTimeZone is in Page_Load it may not retain the selected value which you want to pass to string item = ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue;

Comment: but initTineZone only fills the ddl and the data is seen on page - it works fine.. the other step of getting the value which was selected from the ddl is the problem

Comment: and where is `the other step of getting the value which was selected from the ddl` exactly? Is it in a button click or where?

Comment: it is in an other function fires after button clicked

Comment: Can you add your `Page_Load` code and the button click code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the life cycle of controls in ASP.NET building a dynamic values will "disappear" in the PostBack process.

Try to  call your `initTimeZone` method outside the `if(!IsPostBack)` condition and see if it works. like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)   {
      if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
        //Some Code
      }
      initTimeZone();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Control.EnableViewState for page or parent control.
 Maybe you turn it off?